# How to serve both react application and api from express server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So my node code looks like this (simplified):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const routers = require('./routers');

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}./../dist/`)); // serving index.html

app.use('/api', routers.api);

app.listen(80, () =>
  console.log(`listening on port 80`)
);
```

and let's say my react router has a `/fun/:param` route and a link to the `/fun/foo` page.

If I click the link, I end up on `mypage.com/fun/foo`, but if I refresh I get `Cannot GET /fun/foo`.

Now I understand that what's actually going on is I shoot a request to my express server and it tries to find the `/fun/foo` route, fails and returns `Cannot GET` but how do I make it go to the SPA's `/fun/:param`-ruote?

I found this [link](https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3) and tried to add the following to the bottom:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}./../dist/index.html`));
});
```

If I log incoming requests to the server I get the following when refreshing `/fun/foo`:

```
a connection is made for /fun/foo
a connection is made for /dist/main.js
a connection is made for /fun/main.js
```

and the client shows nothing, the console logs two:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     main.js:1
```

EDIT:

Turns out the `main.js` that is delivered when refreshing the site IS the `index.html`??? (the main.js file on the server is an actual js-file), how does this even happen!?!?!

## New info: Folder structure and relative paths

```
server
   index.js
src
   App.js
   index.js
public -- only used for devServer(?)
   index.html
   favicon.ico
dist  -- what's used in production(?)
   index.html
   main
   main.js
   main.js.map
```

The project is built with webpack

index.html references main.js with:

```
<script src="../dist/main.js"></script>
```

Oh, and if I change the reference to main.js in index.html to:

```
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

I get:

```
Invariant Violation: Minified React error #321; visit
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full
message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and
additional helpful warnings.
```

Comment: What happens when you goto "/dist/main.js" in your browser? Does it serve the JS file? Looks like it's serving HTML (Unexpected token <)

Comment: Yeah it tlooks like the dist/main.js file is an html file but I have no idea how this happens??? It's not an html file when I look at it on the server. I've updated my question with some more info on the folder structure of the project.